# Method naming convention in Scala -- mutable and not version?

Tags: scala, naming-conventions, method-names

*This example is trivial just to show the point.*

Let's say I use matrix library, but is lacks some power, let's say doubling every element in matrix is so crucial for me, I decide to write a method `doubleIt`. However, I could write 2 versions of this method

1. mutable -- `doubleItInPlace`
2. non mutable -- `doubleItByCreatingNewOne`

This is a bit lengthy, so one could think of naming convention, adding to mutable version `_!` suffix, or prefixing it with word "mut".

**Is there any establishing naming convention for making such difference?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The convention is to name the mutable (in general, side-effecting) version with a verb in imperative form. Additionally, and more importantly, use the empty parameter list `()` at the end:

```
def double()
def doubleIt()
```

The immutable version, i.e. one producing a new object, you should name via verb in the passive form. More importantly, do not use the empty parameter list `()` at the end:

```
def doubled
def doubledMatrix
```

Note that naming the non-side-effecting method in the passive form is not always adhered (e.g. the standard collections library), but is a good idea unless it makes the name overly verbose.

Source: [Scala styleguide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#methods).